# Is weakly continuous implies strong continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|_X), (Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ normed spaces, operator $A: X \longrightarrow Y$ weakly continuous. Is $A$ continuous with respect to the **strong** topology?

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: A linear operator between normed spaces is weak-to-weak continuous if and only if it is norm-to-norm continuous, and each of these equivalent conditions is implied by weak-to-norm continuity and implies norm-to-weak continuity. I cannot presently think of any examples of weak-to-norm continuous operators which are not norm-to-norm continuous, but probably there are some, even for $X$ and $Y$ Banach.

Comment: @anonymous, as far as I know all weak-to-norm continuous operators are finite rank